# click button go to next i want to be ablle to get the text value of cell1 and cell2 of each row of a table and store them both in a json list object

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have been struggling with this problem for over a week and i could not figure this out. I have to complete a project that use jquery and json. i am new with both of them. Want i need is when i click on go to next , i want to be able to ge the value of cell1 an cell 2 of each row and add them to my json object that will be sent later to the server for further processing.
I want to be able to store the value of the radio button whether is it yes or no and the text of the second cell.

```html
<div id="accordion>
<div>
<table id=" firm1 ">
<tr id="row1 ">
<td id="td1 ">
<input type="radio " name="response " value="yes ">yes
<input type="radio " name="response " value="no ">no
</td>
<td id="td2 ">
1
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row2 ">
<td id="td1 ">
<input type="radio " name="response " value="yes ">yes
<input type="radio " name="response " value="no ">no
</td>
<td id="td2 ">
2
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<button onclick="getcell1and2ofrows() " >Go to next section</button>
<div>
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

ok i figure out how to do that. i passed the number of row by taking the record count of the element in the model and just loop using for.
i hope it helps someone.

var certificationreponse = function () {// the function called by the button in the view

```
var idtable = $(this).data('tableid-id'); // getting the id of the table
var doccount2 = $(this).data('countdoc-id'); // number of row in the current table



for (var i = 1; i <= doccount2; i++) {

     var el1 = $('#' + idtable).find('tr:eq("'+i+'")').find("td:eq(1)").html();

     var el2 = $('#' + idtable).find('tr:eq("'+i+'")').find('input:checked').val();

    }
```

}